# Adding elements to accordion headings with angular

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, accordion, angular-ui, angularjs-ng-repeat

In the angular application I'm working on, I need to display some data with an accordion and add a button or some other kind of marker to each heading.
Here's an example of what I'm after using the [the Twitter bootstrap accordion](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#collapse):

http://plnkr.co/edit/vV9Ky12jlrKb4qrcRnhA

With just a bit of jQuery, I can append the element I want to the `accordion-toggle` element.

I'm trying to do the same thing using only [angular-ui](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap). Here's what I have so far:

http://plnkr.co/edit/sv43rrvU8rvDHplagZ2v

As you can see, it doesn't quite work as I'd like. The element (here, a simple `span`) is added to the heading as long as I'm not in a `ng-repeat` loop. Obviously, for this loop, the `accordion-heading` is not available yet when I'm plugging my directive. How should I modify it so that it get called at the proper time  (or at least, when the accordion DOM has been compiled) ?

Comment: I was able to get a button in the accordion header with help from a related thread.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/28375623

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of an elegant solution for waiting on the dom to render ng-repeats, but wrapping your dom lookups in the `$timeout` method will get the desired results in this case:

```
$timeout(function(){
    var heading = element.parent().children().find('.accordion-toggle');
    console.log("found heading", heading);
    console.log("adding element", element.html());
    heading.append(element);
    console.log("yay");
},0)
```

[Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/nKFve0IxwdNvCByHfanF?p=preview)